# MVC model Null on post when using Partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC controller where the model on the post method always comes back as null. I'm not sure if this is because I am using a partial view within the form.

Any idea why the model is not being returned to the controller?

**Model**

[image]

**Loading the model**

```
public List<Group> GetStaticMeasures(int businessUnitID)
{
    List<Group> groups = ctx.Groups
                           .Include("Datapoints")
                           .Where(w => w.BusinessUnitID.Equals(businessUnitID))
                           .OrderBy(o => o.SortOrder).ToList();

    groups.ForEach(g => g.Datapoints = g.Datapoints.OrderBy(d => d.SortOrder).ToList());

    return groups;
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Data()
{
    ViewBag.Notification = string.Empty;

    if (User.IsInRole(@"xxx\yyyyyy"))
    {
        List<Group> dataGroups = ctx.GetStaticMeasures(10);
        return View(dataGroups);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new HttpException(403, "You do not have access to the data.");
    }
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Data(List<Group> model)
{
    ViewBag.Notification = string.Empty;

    if (User.IsInRole(@"xxx\yyyyyy"))
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ctx.SaveChanges(model);
            ViewBag.Notification = "Save Successful";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new HttpException(403, "You do not have access to save the data.");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

**Main view**

```
@model List<Jmp.StaticMeasures.Models.Group>

<div class="row">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    { 
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)     

        <div class="large-12">
            <div class="large-8 large-centered columns panel">
                @foreach (var g in @Model)
                { 
                    <h2>@g.Name</h2>
                    foreach (var d in g.Datapoints)
                    { 
                        @Html.Partial("Measures", d)                                 
                    }
                    <hr />
                }   

                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Save Changes"/>

            </div>
        </div>    
    }
</div>
```

**Partial View**

```
@model Jmp.StaticMeasures.Models.Datapoint

@Html.HiddenFor(d => d.ID)
@Html.HiddenFor(d => d.Name) 
@Html.HiddenFor(d => d.SortOrder)

@Html.DisplayTextFor(d => d.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(d => d.StaticValue)   
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.StaticValue)
```

**Rendered Html showing consecutive IDs**

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you've rightly noted, this is because you're using a partial.  This is happening because `Html.Partial` has no idea that it's operating on a collection, so it doesn't generate the names for your form elements with your intention of binding to a collection.

However, the fix in your case appears to be fairly straightforward.  Rather than using `Html.Partial`, you can simply change your partial into an `EditorTemplate` and call `Html.EditorFor` on that template instead.  `Html.EditorFor` is smart enough to know when it's handling a collection, so it will invoke your template for each item in the collection, generating the correct names on your form.

So to do what you need, follow these steps:

1. Create an `EditorTemplates` folder inside your view's current folder (e.g. if your view is `Home\Index.cshtml`, create the folder `Home\EditorTemplates`).  The name is important as it follows a convention for finding templates.
2. Place your partial view in that folder.  Alternatively, put it in the `Shared\EditorTemplates` folder.
3. Rename your partial view to `Datapoint.cshtml` (this is important as template names are based on the convention of the type's name).

Now the relevant view code becomes:

```
// Note:  I removed @ from Model here.
@foreach (var g in Model)
{ 
    <h2>@g.Name</h2>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => g.DataPoints)
    <hr />
}
```

This ensures the separation of your views, as you had originally intended.

### Update per comments

Alright, so as I mentioned below, the problem now is that the model binder has no way of associating a `DataPoint` with the correct `Group`.  The simple fix is to change the view code to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{ 
    <h2>@Model[i].Name</h2>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].DataPoints)
    <hr />
}
```

That will correctly generate the names, and should solve the model binding problem.

**OP's addendum**

Following John's answer I also included the missing properties on the Group table as HiddenFor's which game me the model back on the post.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{ 
    @Html.HiddenFor(t => Model[i].ID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(t => Model[i].BusinessUnitID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(t => Model[i].SortOrder)
    @Html.HiddenFor(t => Model[i].Name)

    <h2>@Model[i].Name</h2>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i].Datapoints)                                 
    <hr />                    
}
```

### Update 2 - Cleaner solution

My advice for using an `EditorTemplate` for each `DataPoint` also applies to each `Group`. Rather than needing the `for` loop, again sprinkling logic in the view, you can avoid that entirely by setting up an `EditorTemplate` for `Group`.  Same steps apply as above in terms of where to put the template.

In this case, the template would be `Group.cshtml`, and would look as follows:

```
@model Jmp.StaticMeasures.Models.Group

<h2>@Model.Name</h2>
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DataPoints)
<hr />
```

As discussed above, this will invoke the template for each item in the collection, which will also generate the correct indices for each `Group`.  Your original view can now be simplified to:

```
@model List<Jmp.StaticMeasures.Models.Group>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    // Other markup
    @Html.EditorForModel();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer towards EditorTemplates. I have changed my implementation and tested but it still does not return the model on the post

Comment: @PhilMurray Did you remove that `@` symbol I mentioned in the note, too?  That shouldn't be there.  Also, check the generated HTML to make sure that you can see sequential indices on your input elements.  If it's possible for `DataPoint` IDs to not be sequential, you'll need to generate an extra `Html.Hidden` field as mentioned in the `Non-Sequential Indices` portion of [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/).

Comment: Yes I did remove the @ on the Model. I have changed the ID in both the parent Group table and the child Datapoint table so that the are sequential but the model still comes back as null in the post action.

Comment: @PhilMurray Ah, I see what the problem is.  If you look closely at the generated HTML, the model binder has no way of associating a `DataPoint` with the correct `Group`.  It will need to generate a name along the lines of `g[0].DataPoints[0]` to do that.  I'm trying to think of an elegant way of doing it.

Comment: @PhilMurray Updating my answer with a solution, give me a moment.

Comment: I think I have fixed it. I needed to add the items from the Group table as HiddenFor's. Just tried it and the post works.

Comment: @PhilMurray That could be a cleaner way of doing things.

Comment: @PhilMurray I have a cleaner way of doing it.  My advice for the `EditorTemplates` applies to each `Group` as well.  I'll update again to show you a cleaner example, which will do the same thing.

Comment: @PhilMurray Updated again.  Thanks for adding your solution to my answer, too.

Comment: @JohnH thanks a lot for this answer my friend. You helped me a TON =-)

Answer (score 1):

Binder can't bind to list of objects if it is returned like this. Yes, partial is your problem. You need to specify a number within your form for ID's.

Do something like this:

```
 // pseudocode
@model List<Jmp.StaticMeasures.Models.Group>

<div class="row">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    { 
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)     

        <div class="large-12">
            <div class="large-8 large-centered columns panel">
                    for(int i; i<Model.Count; i++)
                    { 
                        <h2>@g.Name</h2>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(d => Model[i].Id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(d => Model[i].Name) 
                        @Html.HiddenFor(d => Model[i].SortOrder)

                        @Html.DisplayTextFor(d => Model[i].Name)
                        @Html.EditorFor(d => Model[i].StaticValue)   
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => Model[i].StaticValue)  
                        <hr />
                    }

                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Save Changes"/>

            </div>
        </div>    
    }
</div>
```

See more details about binding to a list in [Haack's blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a null model because of the way the model binder handles collections.

Your partial view is rendering those inputs as for example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="1"/>
...
```

And then repeating that for each entry in your `List<Group>`. Unfortunately the model binder won't know how to handle that and you'll get a null value.

The way your inputs have to look is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="groups[0].ID" value="1"/>
...
<input type="hidden" name="groups[1].ID" value="2"/>
```

There can't be a break in the numbering. One way to get this is to rewrite the way you use the Html.xxxFor methods, e.g.: iterate over the list and do this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(d => Model[i].Id)
```

Here are two resources that explain this in detail and provide yet other examples of how to make the model binder work with collections:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/