# C# MVC - View returns Model null on Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have absolutely no idea of why the model is null after submitting the form.....I have checked the **FormCollection**, but it only contains "ScriptAssignments.Assigned". Im using a strongly typed view, and im using a beginform....I don't get whats wrong here...I will appreciate any help.

**This is how the View looks like.....**

```
@model Models.ScriptAssignmentMatrix

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Script Matrix";
}

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/RotatedHeaders.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<h1>Assignment Matrix</h1>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveChanges", "ScriptMatrix",FormMethod.Post)) {
<div style=" height:15px"></div>    
<table class="table table-striped table-header-rotated">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th> 
        @foreach (var header in Model.ColumnHeaders) 
        {
            <th>
                <div class="container"><div class="head"><div class="vert">
                    <span style="font-size: 10pt">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => header)
                    </span>
                </div></div></div>
            </th>
        }
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    @foreach (var row in Model.RowHeaders)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span style="font-size: 10pt; background: #eee; ">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => row)
                </span>
            </td>
            @foreach (var header in Model.ColumnHeaders)
            {
                var ScriptAssignments = (from y in Model.ScriptAssignments
                               where y.AgentName == row && y.ScriptName == header
                               select y).First();
                <td>     
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(Assignment => ScriptAssignments.Assigned) 
                </td>
            }
        </tr>

    }
    </tbody>

</table>

<div style=" height:30px"></div>    
<input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
<div style=" height:30px"></div>    
 @ViewBag.Result
```

}

This is the Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult SaveChanges(ScriptAssignmentMatrix model)
    {

        ViewBag.Result = "Your changes have been saved";
        return View("Index", model);
    }
```

This is the ScriptAssignmentMatrix class:

```
public class ScriptAssignmentMatrix
{
    public List<ScriptAssignmentMatrixElement> ScriptAssignments { get; set; }
    public List<String> ColumnHeaders { get; set; }
    public List<String> RowHeaders { get; set; }
}

public class ScriptAssignmentMatrixElement
{
    public int ScriptId { get; set; }
    public string  ScriptName { get; set; }

    public int AgentId { get; set; }
    public string AgentName { get; set; }

    public bool Assigned { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Might be a problem with the `foreach`. Use a `for` loop instead. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21575296).

Comment: `DisplayFor` doesn't create an `input` element.  To fix it, use `HiddenFor` after each `DisplayFor`

Comment: The DisplayFor is being used only for the table headers...the data that needs to be saved inside the model is inside the nested foreach

Comment: In my few experience with CheckboxFor in a nested foreach, the way it works for me is with a for loop as @gunr2171 comment. Give it a try.

Comment: Model binding may not occur correctly if you don't post the header values using a `HiddenFor` field.  MVC likes to get all of the model fields back during a post to do it's binding.  Try adding the hidden fields and see what happens.

Comment: When posting back, anything that you want to come back properly needs to have a "Name" on the html element that binds to something in your model.. and ScriptAssignments.Assign does not actually bind to anything which in turn leads to it not returning anything in your model

Comment: Already tried.....no luck.....however changing the foreach to for had some impact.....at least now I get all the instances of ScriptAssignments.Assigned instead of only one...but I still fail to get the entire model.

Answer (score 1):

DisplayFor doesnot bind the control with the model. So the best way is to use HiddenFor.

```
@foreach (var header in Model.ColumnHeaders) 
{
    <th>
        <div class="container"><div class="head"><div class="vert">
            <span style="font-size: 10pt">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => header)
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => header)
            </span>
        </div></div></div>
    </th>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found the answer....still cant explain why.....but this is the working modified code of the view.....

**Thanks gunr2171 and Jorge F....your comments put me in the right track.....**

```
Models.ScriptAssignmentMatrix

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Script Matrix";
}

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/RotatedHeaders.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<h1>Assignment Matrix</h1>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveChanges", "ScriptMatrix",FormMethod.Post)) {

<div style=" height:15px"></div>    
<table class="table table-striped table-header-rotated">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th> 
        @foreach (var header in Model.ColumnHeaders) 
        {
            <th>
                <div class="container"><div class="head"><div class="vert">
                    <span style="font-size: 10pt">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => header)
                    </span>
                </div></div></div>
            </th>
        }
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    @for (int row = 0; row < Model.RowHeaders.Count; row++ )
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span style="font-size: 10pt; background: #eee; ">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.RowHeaders[row])
                </span>
            </td>
            @for (int column = 0; column < Model.ColumnHeaders.Count; column++ )
            {

                for (int index = 0; index < Model.ScriptAssignments.Count; index++)
                {
                     if (Model.ScriptAssignments[index].AgentName == Model.RowHeaders[row] && Model.ScriptAssignments[index].ScriptName == Model.ColumnHeaders[column])
                     {
                        <td>     
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(Assignment =>  Model.ScriptAssignments[index].Assigned) 
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x =>  Model.ScriptAssignments[index].AgentId)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x =>  Model.ScriptAssignments[index].ScriptId)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x =>  Model.ScriptAssignments[index].AgentName)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x =>  Model.ScriptAssignments[index].ScriptName)
                        </td>                             
                         break;
                     }

                }                    
            }
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>

</table>

<div style=" height:30px"></div>    

<input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
<div style=" height:30px"></div>    
 @ViewBag.Result
```

}