# .NET MVC C# Error - A data source must be bound before this operation can be performed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am encountering the following error:

**A data source must be bound before this operation can be performed.**

I have a text box, the user enters a name, and clicks the submit button. The name is added to a list. I have researched the error but everything I try gives me the same error. Any insight on what I am doing wrong will be appreciated.

Model:

```
namespace RangeTest.Models
{
    public class UserNameModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Names Added List")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }    

     }

}
```

Controller:

```
   public ActionResult Admin()
    {


        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Admin(UserNameModel model, IEnumerable<RangeTest.Models.UserNameModel> t)
    {

        List<UserNameModel> userList = new List<UserNameModel>();
        model.FullName = t.FirstOrDefault().FullName;
        userList.Add(model);

        return View(userList.ToList());

    }
```

View (Admin.cshtml):

```
@model IEnumerable<RangeTest.Models.UserNameModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "";
 }
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="jumbotron">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Admin", "UserNames", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "WebGridForm" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


    WebGrid dataGrid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: false, canSort: false);
    //Func<bool, MvcHtmlString> func =
    //(b) => b ? MvcHtmlString.Create("checked=\"checked\"") : MvcHtmlString.Empty;

    <div class="table-bordered">
        <div class="Title">Admin - Add names to range list</div><br />
        <table id="TblAdd"class="table">

            <tr>

                @{
                    RangeTest.Models.UserNameModel t = new RangeTest.Models.UserNameModel();
                }
                @Html.Partial("_AddDynTable", t)
        </table>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <div class="Title">Names Added to Range List</div>
                    <table class="table">

                        <tr>

                            <td >
                                @dataGrid.GetHtml(columns: dataGrid.Columns(dataGrid.Column(format: @<text>@item</text>),
                                       dataGrid.Column("", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.id }))))
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
}

    </div>
```

Partial View (_addDynTable.cshtml)

```
@model RangeTest.Models.UserNameModel


<tr>
    <td>
        Enter Full Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FullName)
  @*<input type="button" value="Create" id="ClickToAdd" />*@<input class="CreateBtn" type="submit" value="Add to List" /></td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you link info about the error please?

One thing I can see is your t object is null when you pass it to the partial view

RangeTest.Models.UserNameModel t = new RangeTest.Models.UserNameModel();

A new UserNameModel with no data in it, if your error is there that might be the problem

Comment: This is exactly what is happening, I have copied your code to a project and the error is at this line in your partial view. So you are showing a gridview with with null as datasource.

Comment: Steve, the rest of your comment seems to be cut off. The UserNameModel will be null until a user enters a name.

Comment: Definately because the use of a partial view. Have a look at :

[MVC model Null on post when using Partial view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574961/mvc-model-null-on-post-when-using-partial-view)