# MVC model is null in controller during HTTP Post ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I post data via submit, I see that model is null in controller. I already see that this question is asked many times, and the root cause is the name conflict between model property name and the  same name we use in action parameter of controller. But this is not the case in my scenario. Not sure why the model is null. Any help is appreciated. In the below code, "pm" variable is null.

View:

```
<div>  @Html.LabelFor(model =>model.procedureName)</div>
<div>   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.procedureName)</div>
<div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.procedureName)</div>
<div>   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ServiceDate)</div>
<div> @Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model.ServiceDate) </div>
<div> @using (Html.BeginForm())
          { 
          <input type="submit" value="Save Procedure" id="btnPost" />
          }


</div>
```

Model:

```
public partial class MemberProcedure
{
    public int procedureid { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a name")]
    public string procedureName { get; set; }
    public string updatedbyUserName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdatetime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Createtime { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a service date")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ServiceDate { get; set; }
}
```

Controller action method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Procedure(MemberProcedure pm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

           savedata....
        }
        return View(pm);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<input id="procedureName" name="procedureName" type="text" value="">
<input id="ServiceDate" name="ServiceDate" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: your form comes after all your inputs.  your inputs need to be enclosed in the form.

Comment: *All* your controls need to go inside the `Html.BeginForm()`, not just the submit button.

Comment: why do you not put control in the form tag.. it will never set properties of the class object in this way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC model Null on post when using Partial view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574961/mvc-model-null-on-post-when-using-partial-view)

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like all of your input elements are outside of your form tag. Try this instead:

```
<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    <div>@Html.LabelFor(model =>model.procedureName)</div>
    <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.procedureName)</div>
    <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.procedureName)</div>
    <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ServiceDate)</div>
    <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model.ServiceDate) </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Save Procedure" id="btnPost" />
}
</div>
```

With the elements outside of the form tags, they never get submitted.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your form comes after all your inputs. Your inputs need to be enclosed in the form.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {     
    <div>@Html.LabelFor(model =>model.procedureName)</div>
    <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.procedureName)</div>
    <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.procedureName)</div>
    <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ServiceDate)</div>
    <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model.ServiceDate)</div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Save Procedure" id="btnPost" /></div>    
}
```